# How would I rearrange the order on an inline-block in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a row of buttons that are all next to each other in an inline-block under the class "member actions". I would like to rearrange the order of these buttons. Also I would like to add a small icon to the left of these. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Here's the code:

```
 .member_actions {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 96px;

}

.member_actions .send_gift a{
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #6c829b;
    line-height: 21px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    background: image(btn_bg_red_big.png) repeat-x top left #c62800;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
}
.member_actions .block_profile a{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #6c829b;
    line-height: 21px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    background: image(btn_small_red.jpg) repeat-x top left #8ea3be;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
}

 .member_actions .send_message a{
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #6c829b;
    line-height: 21px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    background: image(btn_bg_red_big.png) repeat-x top left #c62800;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;

}

.member_actions .send_friend_request a, .member_actions .send_profile a, .member_actions .bookmark a {

    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #6c829b;
    line-height: 21px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
    margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    background: image(btn_small_red.jpg) repeat-x top left #8ea3be;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;

}
```

Also a screenshot so that you can visualize it. Thanks![image: Buttons!]

Comment: Please post the html as well. Re-ordering should be accomplished in the html. There are several ways to add the icon (using <img> tag or creating a div and setting it as a background-image through css, for example).

Comment: Also, it seems you have an error where .block is floated and absolutely positioned. It should just be display-inline, same as the others. I recommend you put as much as you can into a common class ".nav_button", and then make more specific classes ".nav_button.red" for elements that are varied. This will make sure there is less conflicting logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rearrange the `.member_actions` buttons you can add `position: absolute` to the class, then use `.member_actions:nth-child(1)`, `.member_actions:nth-child(2)` and so on and add `left: -50px` to position element 50 pixels to the left, or `left: 50px` to position element 50 pixels to the right. See sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug8gK/)

To add a small icon, again use `.member_actions:nth-child(n)` , where n is 1, 2, 3 etc. to target specific element, add `background: url("path_to_img.png") 0 0 no-repeat;` --> 0 pixels from the left, 0 from the top, and add `padding-left: 40px` assuming 40px is the width of your image, if not change the value accordingly. This will drop the background image left from the text and add padding to the text, so it doesn't overlap the image.

Comment: This is only a good solution if you are unable to edit the html. Manually setting positions by measuring pixels is considered unnecessary and very poor form otherwise.

Comment: Fully agree, but that was not the question.